# Rails custom logger with separate file and tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

I want to implement a logger gem which when included will write some logs into separate file, and I will be able to add custom tags when necessary (and it will 'remember' them along the code). This logger will be in addition to the default logger and will include special alerts.

For now I have a module which exposes this logger, but I was unable to add tags with `TaggedLogging`, because I access the logger via `Logging.logger[logger_name]`, and I don't have such access with `TaggedLogging`.

lib/special_alerts_logger.rb:

```
module SpecialAlerts
  def self.logger
    Logging.logger['special_alerts']
  end
end
```

config/initializers/special_alerts.rb

```
logger_name = 'special_alerts'
logger = Logging.logger[logger_name]

logger.add_appenders Logging.appenders.rolling_file("log/#{logger_name}.log",
                                                    age: 'weekly',
                                                    layout: Logging.layouts.pattern(pattern: '[%d] %-5l %c: %m\n'),
                                                    level: :info)
```

Is there a neat way of doing such a thing?

Comment: How about adding a tag in your `layout` under `special_alerts.rb`?